# Dropped event message OpenNLP. Training data is dropped in OpenNLP

Tags: training-data, opennlp, categorization

I have labeled data (label and text), like this:

```
category1, "train message 1"
category1, "train message 2"
category1, "train message 3"
category2, "train message 4"
category2, "train messsage 5"
```

I try to train my **categorize model** with Java OpenNLP  library.

`DoccatModel model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("pt", sampleStream, params, customFactory);`

When i training model, i get strange messages:

```
**Indexing events using cutoff of 5**
**Computing event counts...  done. 5441 events**
Dropped event animals*:[bow=live, bow=animals, ng=:live:animals]
Dropped event animals*:[bow=aquariums]
Dropped event animals*:[bow=aquatic, bow=plant, bow=fertilizers, ng=:aquatic:plant,ng=:aquatic:plant:fertilizers, ng=:plant:fertilizers]
Dropped event apparel*:[bow=activewear]
Dropped event apparel*:[bow=one, bow=pieces, ng=:one:pieces]
```

Why does it mean **Dropped event** "*category*": [....]?**

Comment: It happened when in training data there are similars phrase, i think....

Comment: Who anybody see same event?

Comment: Does a neural network skip any samples?

Comment: Did you find what is the issue?

Comment: I used more training data and updated my OpenNLP to 1.8 version, but not last 1.9.0 After that, this problem resolved.
I think,  training data was bad and not corrected. I had 5900 training data samples and Open NLP is not skip it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added custom factory, it work

```
int minNgramSize = 2;
int maxNgramSize = 3;
DoccatFactory customFactory = new DoccatFactory(new FeatureGenerator[]{
            new BagOfWordsFeatureGenerator(),
            new NGramFeatureGenerator(minNgramSize, maxNgramSize)
            });
DoccatModel model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("pt", sampleStream, params, customFactory);
```